# How to create a seperate commenting system?

Tags: comments, custom-content

I'm planning to add a question and answers (custom post type) to my website. I already use my default WP comment system on my posts. Now I want a custom content type for my question post type to be answered by users. It needs to behaves 100% similar to WP comment system.
My needs:
1. Users submit answers(comment) with EMail Name URL and answer, I and other user roles approves them on backend.
2. Seperate menu from comments in wp-admin.
3. Looks somewhat and behaves 100% like edit-comments.php with all features.
4. Don't know about internal CSS, so CSS too. I can take care of the template CSs.
5. Clicking on User name goes to his URL and open in new tab.
6. For login users - comment form fills the name and email like comment forms.

Well, I'm not sure if its possible to achieve. If its possible, how to do it ?. Any suggestions to external links will also be help full.